# how to visualize GATE TENSOR in TENSORBOARD while using multitask network like MMOE/PLE

Tags: tensorflow

while training a multitask network in recommendation system using network like MMOE, I want to observe the parameters of GATE network to know whether the gate network is able to distinguish samples from different tasks?

for example:

1. if it is a positive sample of click, the gate network will give high weight for CLICK EXPERTS; if it is a positive sample of pay, the gate network will give high weight for PAY EXPERTS;
2. if the gate network is not well-trained, then the network will give both CLICK and PAY EXPERTS the same weight;

how can I use tensorboard to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are options in Tensorboards you can examine the gateway input/output at each layer by input series and distributions.

> Q: if it is a positive sample of click, the gate network will give high weight for CLICK EXPERTS; if it is a positive sample of pay, the gate network will give high weight for PAY EXPERTS;

A: Positive sample is when the input continues to provide the continuous result, you can logging with the function tf.summary() that can be displayed on the Tensorboard.

> Q: if the gate network is not well-trained, then the network will give both CLICK and PAY EXPERTS the same weight;

A: Data logging display input data.

Write into file, you can add label, custom value or image.

Sample: Input data image, the input can be array

```
with file_writer.as_default():
        for i in range(10):
            tf.summary.image("Training data", tf.constant( list_image_greyscales[i], shape=(1,32,32,1) ), step=i)
```

Graph drawings can reflect of anytime loggings.

[image: Sample]